# torch7: Unable to load BMP images

Tags: image, lua, bmp, torch

I am trying to load some images to train my conv-net. I am using '**image**' package of torch7 for that purpose. But, during loading images as follows:

```
local img_raw = image.load(train_path .. train_files[i]):mul(255)
```

I am getting the following error on trying to load a BMP file:

```
/path/to/torch/install/bin/luajit: /path/to/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:737: <image.load> unknown image type: bmp
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /path/to/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/dok/inline.lua:737: in function 'error'
    /path/to/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/image/init.lua:337: in function 'load'
    final_2.lua:310: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    .../torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:131: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x00406670
```

Can someone please suggest some way to load BMP images for further processing in torch7?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find a library that supports them or write support for that format for the `image` package?

Comment: Alternatively: use this [Lua / Torch wrapper around graphicsmagick](https://github.com/clementfarabet/graphicsmagick). Or convert your images to PNG or PPM format beforehand with {image,graphics}magick.

Comment: @deltheil, thanks. I installed **graphicsmagick** package but I was having trouble importing it my script. So, I decided to convert the few BMP images which I had to JPEG format, and hence, bypassed the above error.

Answer (score 0):

Just for completeness,  I'll throw some code here:

First, install graphics magic

`$ luarocks install graphicsmagick`

Then

```
require 'image'
gm = require 'graphicsmagick'

-- change the string
local jpg_filename = string.gsub(train_files[i],".[Bb][Mm][Pp]$",".jpg")
-- get the info so we can build the size string
local image_info = gm.info(train_path .. train_files[i])
-- convert takes a size string h x w
local size_string = image_info["height"] .. "x" .. image_info["width"]

gm.convert{
  input = train_path .. train_files[i],
  output = train_path .. jpg_filename,
  size = size_string,
  quality = 95,
  verbose = true
}
local img_raw = image.load(train_path .. jpg_filename):mul(255)
```